# Grant all ARO records specific ACOs in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, command-line-interface, acl

In CakePHP I am wondering if there is a way to grant ALL ARO's a specific ACO via shell

eg: `$ cake acl grant * Posts`

I know you can do it in code via `$this->Auth->allow('actionName');` but ideally I would like to do this outside of code where possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the root of AROs:

`cake acl grant {RootGroup} {Controller/Action} {permission}`

The `RootGroup` will grant the permission to all. See more here: 
[Can ACL allow all, but deny for one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364878/can-acl-allow-all-but-deny-for-one)

Comment: That works for RootGroup but the idea is to give the permission to *, eg: everyone, including people not set in a group, like a visitor.

Comment: This is the reverse way to think about permissions (so to speak). To accomplish this, you need to create a GUEST user and then anyone who is not "authorized" will inherit the guest user permissions.